# Number validate at keypress

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui

I validate the phone number using below code its working fine but i allow char at first time while user entering the values. how i can solve it. . . .

```
$('.Number').keypress(function () {
    $('.Number').keypress(function (event) {
        var keycode;

        keycode = event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which;

        if (!(event.shiftKey == false && (keycode == 46 || keycode == 8 ||
                keycode == 37 ||keycode == 39 || (keycode >= 48 && keycode <= 57)))) {
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first character is unrestricted because you have nested `keypress` handlers. Try this:

```
$('.Number').keypress(function (event) {
    var keycode = event.which;
    if (!(event.shiftKey == false && (keycode == 46 || keycode == 8 || keycode == 37 || keycode == 39 || (keycode >= 48 && keycode <= 57)))) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Comment: good. handled all important non-digit keys

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
$('.Number').keyup(function (event) {
    var keycode = event.which;
    if (!(event.shiftKey == false && (keycode == 46 || keycode == 8 || keycode == 37 || keycode == 39 || (keycode >= 48 && keycode <= 57)))) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a function that will validate the input.  It will return true if the value is a number, false otherwise.  Numbers are charcode 48 - 57.  This function also allows all control characters to return true. (<32)

```
function isNumber(evt)
{
   evt = (evt) ? evt : window.event;
   var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;
   if (charCode > 32 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)) {
      return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

[Here is a chart of the codes.](https://www.w3schools.com/charsets/ref_html_ascii.asp)

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
<title>number validation</title>
<script>
    function checkNumber(check)
    {   
        var a = document.getElementById("txt_contact_no").value;
        //var x=check.which;
        //var x = a.charCode;
        var x = a.keyCode;
        if(!(a >= 48 || a <= 57))
        {
            alert("enter only numbers");
            return false;
        }       
        else if(a=="" || a==null)
        {
            alert("field is blank");
            return false;
        }
// if no is more then the value 
        /*else if (a.length <= 9)
        {
            alert("enter minimum 10 characters");
            return false;
        }*/
        alert("done");
        return true;        
    }
</script>
</script>
</head>
<body>
<table>
<form name=form1 method=post action="#">
    <tr>
        <td>
        <b>Subjects</b><input type="text" name="contact_no" id="txt_contact_no" onblur="checkNumber(this)"> 
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><p id="p1"></p></td>
    </tr>
</form>
</table>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the simplest solution for KeyPress Number Events:

```js
 $(document).ready(function(){    
    $(".Number").keypress(function(event){
        var keycode = event.which;
        if (!(keycode >= 48 && keycode <= 57)) {
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    });
 });
```